# max of images correlation with xcorr2 shifted by 2 pixels compared to imfilter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

preparing lab code for real-time fixed point implementation, I wrote the following function

```
function res =  imcorr(inIm,kernel)
% res=imfilter(inIm,kernel,'replicate'); %initial implementation
% res=imfilter(inIm,kernel); %same as we crop the result below
res=xcorr2(inIm,kernel); %faster, works with singles, but shifts result by 2 pixels

s=size(inIm);
rect=[fix((size(res,2)-s(2))/2), fix((size(res,1)-s(1))/2), s(2), s(1)];
res=imcrop(res,rect);
```

then I used the code from https://gist.github.com/goulu/ba70175f870fdb2c25e3 ( edited from http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html ) as testbench and noticed there is a 2 pixels shift in both directions between the results obtained by xcorr2 and imfilter:

[image]

where does this come from ?

Comment: Could you try with a manually generated matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know exactly why but it seems imfilter and xcorr2 do rounding differently with odd/even image sizes, so finally I could obtain the same results by cropping like this :

```
rect=[(size(res,2)-s(2))/2+1.5 (size(res,1)-s(1))/2+1.5 s(2)-1-yoff s(1)-1-xoff];
res=imcrop(res,fix(rect));
```